# Click Handlers for Trees in GXT 3?

Tags: event-handling, tree, gxt

I've been looking through [GXT3's `Tree` API](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.0-rc2/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/tree/Tree.html) for some way to execute an action when I click or double click on a node in a tree, and I can't seem to find anything that would work.

I know `TreeGrid` has a `CellClickHandler` and `CellDoubleClick` handler, but there doesn't seem to be anything similar for `Tree`. There's the generic `addHandler` method inherited from `Widget` but this seems like it would apply to the whole tree, not a specific node.

Is there something I'm overlooking, or a different / better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

use the `TreePanel`'s selection model:

```java
treePanel.getSelectionModel().addSelectionChangedListener(
        new SelectionChangedListener<BaseTreeModel>() {

            @Override
            public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent<BaseTreeModel> se) {

                BaseTreeModel selectedItem = se.getSelectedItem();

                // implement functionality
            }
        }
);
```

see the [`TreePanel` API](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-2.2.5/docs/api/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/tree/Tree.html) for a reference.

Comment: Thanks for the response Eliran. Unless I'm mistaken, TreePanel is from GXT 2 and no longer exists in GXT3, as they changed how the trees worked. Either way, I realized just now that there is a cell action tree implementation in the GXT explorer that can be used for what I need.

Comment: oh, i didn't notice you're referring to version 3. anyhow please add the solution as an answer to your question so others may benefit from it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use this for Single Selection

```
    tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
    tree.getSelectionModel().addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<MenuView.MenuDto>() {

        public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<MenuDto> event) {
            MenuDto mnu = event.getSelectedItem();
            Info.display("Tree Handler", mnu.getDescripcion());
        }
    });
```

For Multiple Selections

```
    tree.getSelectionModel().addSelectionChangedHandler(new SelectionChangedHandler<MenuView.MenuDto>() {

        public void onSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent<MenuDto> event) {
            List<MenuDto> mnus = event.getSelection();
            Info.display("Tree Handler", mnus.get(0).getDescripcion());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to override Tree's onDoubleClick (or onClick) method:

```
Tree tree = new Tree<MyModel, String>(store, valueProvider){            
    @Override
    protected void onDoubleClick(Event event) {
        TreeNode<MyModel> node = findNode(event.getEventTarget().<Element> cast());
        Info.display("Double Click", "You double clicked this node!");
        super.onDoubleClick(event);
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.This can be achieved by using the Cell Action Tree, an implementation of which can be found here: http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:cellactiontree