# Gxt tree grid double click to show pop up

Tags: java, gwt, event-handling, gxt, treegrid

How do I catch double click event in gxt tree grid?
I already try this from : 
[Click Handlers for Trees in GXT 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743869/click-handlers-for-trees-in-gxt-3)

```
tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
tree.getSelectionModel().addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<MenuView.MenuDto>() {

    public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<MenuDto> event) {
        MenuDto mnu = event.getSelectedItem();
        Info.display("Tree Handler", mnu.getDescripcion());
    }
});
```

But it only works for single click, not double click.
I want if user press double click, pop up will show.

Comment: gwt and gxt is used java, i already change tag, thank.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11088398/2982225

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion that not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selection has specific meaning in this case - are you sure you want *doubleclick* to cause selection to happen, and only *then* you want to be notified?

Instead, look at `grid.addRowDoubleClickHandler` - your handler will be given the row index that was clicked, and you can then ask the store what item is in that row.

Relevant GXT Javadoc:

- [`grid.addRowDoubleClickHandler(...)`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/gxt/3.1/javadoc/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/grid/Grid.html#addRowDoubleClickHandler(com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.event.RowDoubleClickEvent.RowDoubleClickHandler))
- [`RowDoubleClickEvent`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/gxt/3.1/javadoc/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/event/RowDoubleClickEvent.html)

Comment: thank colin alworth, i try use addRowDoubleClickHandler and work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code, i only test to see info display :

```
tree.addRowDoubleClickHandler(new RowDoubleClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onRowDoubleClick(RowDoubleClickEvent event) {
        Info.display("hello", "double click");
    }
});
```